# Is a SqlConnection automatically closed when an application is closed?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlconnection

I am querying the db in a separate thread.

If I close the application while the query is being executed, will the SqlConnection automatically close or will it remain open?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the process is terminated, all the OS resources, including network connections, will be released. In other words - that's fine.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: It's certainly not an excuse to avoid closing down connections promptly etc. But it's a reason not worry if your app goes down while doing something *reasonably* harmless. Dying half way through writing a new data file etc is slightly harder to cope with (although doable of course).

Comment: Becuase i have see in some cases that the application is closed, but when you query in sql-server to see the active connections, still shows up those connections.

Comment: @Vanilla: It's possible that the network connections are in time-wait or something similar - but I'd expect to see them drop off reasonably quickly. What sort of connection are you using to the database?

Comment: @Vanilla: No, I mean which network transport - TCP/IP, named pipes etc. It may well make a difference to how quickly the resource is cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

If the application ends, the connection gets closed, along with everything else that was opened.

Answer (score 0):

A SqlConnection is a disposable object. In general it is always good practice to Dispose() of objects that implement IDisposable. I also noticed SqlConnection objects have a Close() method. Should you call that too? Well, I found this article with more info on this:

[SqlConnection: To Close or To Dispose?](http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2009/03/12/1210.aspx)